# How can I install BeautifulSoup? I keep getting "No module named bs4"

Tags: python

When I try to import Beautifulsoup

```
import bs4
```

I keep getting the error

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I have tried to address this by trying all of the following (individually and together) with Python 3 and have had no success. What's going wrong?

```
sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4
sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro Hey there, I've added an answer there. I hope that works for ya.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach appears to be working:

```
sudo pip3.6 install bs4
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```